# Levene test in R for the datafram below

Tags: r

`dput(head(Clean, 100))`

```
structure(list(`Reporting unit` = c("Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", "Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]", 
"Albury Wodonga Health [Albury Campus]"), `Reporting unit type` = c("Hospital", 
"Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", 
"Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital"), State = c("NSW", "NSW", 
"NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW", "NSW"), `Local Hospital Network (LHN)` = c("Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", 
"Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health", "Albury Wodonga Health"
), `Peer group` = c("Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", 
"Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", 
"Large hospitals", "Large hospitals", "Large hospitals"), `Time period` = c("2011–12", 
"2012–13", "2013–14", "2014–15", "2015–16", "2016–17", "2011–12", 
"2012–13", "2013–14", "2014–15"), Category = c("Cellulitis", 
"Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", "Cellulitis", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)", 
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (without complications)"
), `Total number of stays` = c(111, 116, 141, 155, 210, 196, 
109, 116, 75, 132), `Number of overnight stays` = c(92, 98, 115, 
123, 166, 155, 108, 113, 71, 122), `Percentage of overnight stays` = c(0.83, 
0.84, 0.82, 0.79, 0.79, 0.79, 0.99, 0.97, 0.95, 0.92), `Average length of stay (days)` = c(3.9, 
3.3, 3.1, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 5.8, 4.6, 5.7, 4.4), `Peer group average (days)` = c(3.7, 
3.5, 3.3, 3.2, 3, 3, 4.8, 4.4, 4.2, 3.9), `Total overnight patient bed days` = c(356, 
326, 351, 306, 431, 418, 622, 518, 405, 538)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hi I'm trying to do a levene test for the above data frame between the peer group (large and medium hospitals) and Average length but I get the following error:

> Error in leveneTest.formula(Clean$group ~ Clean$`Average length of stay (days)`,  : 
>     Levene's test is not appropriate with quantitative explanatory variables.

Can someone help, please.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order in your formula:

```
leveneTest(Clean$`Average length of stay (days)`~Clean$`Peer group`)
```

Comment: Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In leveneTest.default(y = y, group = group, ...) : group coerced to factor.                                     I get this error above is this a problem?

Comment: No, it just tells you that `Peer group` variable was silently coerced from `character` to `factor`. That's a technical detail that do not affect resuls of `leveneTest`

Answer (score 1):

The fiollowing can solve the problem.

1. If the formula interface is used, there is no need for the data.frame name in it, only in argument `data`.
2. The order of the formula's terms should be reversed, the explanatory variable should be on the RHS.

And since the package where `leveneTest` might not be loaded, I prefix the function call.

```
car::leveneTest(`Average length of stay (days)` ~ `Peer group`, data = Clean)
```

Also, the column names are not syntactically valid, spaces in the names need back ticks.

```
names(Clean) <- make.names(names(Clean))
```